# assigning a value corresponding to an indicator in r

Tags: r, dplyr, indicator

| id | time | value1 | indicator | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2004 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2005 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 2006 | -1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 2007 | -3 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 2008 | 3 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 2004 | 1 | 0 | NA |
| 2 | 2005 | 3 | 0 | NA |
| 2 | 2006 | 0 | 0 | NA |
| 2 | 2007 | 0 | 0 | NA |
| 3 | 2004 | -1 | 1 | -1 |
| 3 | 2005 | -3 | 0 | -1 |
| 3 | 2006 | 4 | 0 | -1 |
| 3 | 2007 | 5 | 0 | -1 |
| 4 | 2004 | 4 | 0 | -4 |
| 4 | 2005 | 5 | 0 | -4 |
| 4 | 2006 | 2 | 0 | -4 |
| 4 | 2007 | -4 | 1 | -4 |

Indicator is a binary variable. The desired output is value 2. If indicator is 0, its value 2 takes a value 2 of the year when indicator is 1. It is grouped by id. If an id does not have any 1 for indicator, value2 takes NA's.

Comment: Is `value2` the desired output? Or is `value2` part of the input and you want to modify it somehow?

Comment: Can you rephrase the last sentence? The "if it is 0" and "when indicator is 1" seem to refer to the same clause.

Comment: sorry guys, I edited!

Comment: What have you tried so far and why it didn't work?

Comment: Hi RobertoT. I made another dataset with only rows with value of 1 in indicator. Then merged the new dataset with the original one by gvkey. This seems a rough solution for me so I was looking for a cleaner dplyr solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(value2 = ifelse(indicator == 1, value1 , NA)
  ) %>% 
  tidyr::fill(value2, .direction  = "updown")
```

Result:

```
      id  time value1 indicator value2
   <int> <int>  <int>     <int>  <int>
 1     1  2004      1         1      1
 2     1  2005      0         0      1
 3     1  2006     -1         0      1
 4     1  2007     -3         0      1
 5     1  2008      3         0      1
 6     2  2004      1         0     NA
 7     2  2005      3         0     NA
 8     2  2006      0         0     NA
 9     2  2007      0         0     NA
10     3  2004     -1         1     -1
11     3  2005     -3         0     -1
12     3  2006      4         0     -1
13     3  2007      5         0     -1
14     4  2004      4         0     -4
15     4  2005      5         0     -4
16     4  2006      2         0     -4
17     4  2007     -4         1     -4
```

Comment: If you click the green arrow, the answer gets classified as answered. Glad to help :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I have been wondering why the arrow button does not work but just found the check button haha. Please tell me if it is done correctly and have a nice day